# How to autofill down based on another column in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to autofill a range based on the number of values in column A. Here is my code:

```
Dim Pricing As Worksheet
Dim lrp As Long

lrp = Pricing.Range("A3" & Pricing.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Pricing.Range("B3:AR3").AutoFill Destination:=Pricing.Range("B3:AR" & lrp)
```

The pricing worksheet data starts in column 3 and starts in column B and goes all the way to AR. When I run this code, no error appears. No data gets autofilled down.

I need the range to auto fill down based on the adjacent column (Column A). Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Do you have formulae in row 3? Are you defining `Pricing` somewhere?

Comment: remove 3 in "A3"

Comment: I have pricing defined and there is a formula in B3 to AR3

Comment: I think @pokemon_Man has nailed it.

Comment: Thanks so much guys. Any reason why I had to take out the 3?

Comment: Though your code errors for me when I try it.

Comment: Pricing.Rows.Count is already the total count of rows in column A, don't need to specify it in the "A3"

Comment: I am also now having an issue where my headers read "N/A"

Comment: This code won't work without Setting the _Worksheet Pricing_ or using the _Worksheet Index_